# SQL - UPDATE query (moving decimal points)

Tags: sql, decimal, sybase

I need an update query to take a particular field and move decimal points.

```
SELECT amount FROM transaction table WHERE id = 20

Amount 
12987
```

Need an update query

```
UPDATE transaction
SET amount = amount/100
WHERE id = 20
```

Will this work?

```
SELECT amount FROM transaction table WHERE id = 20

Amount
129.87
```

Comment: Yes, that is valid SQL and would update the record you specify.  What makes you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: What is the type of the column `amount`?

Comment: Try it out after executing ``begin transaction;``. Then you can select and otherwise look around. If you are satisfied, execute ``commit transaction;``. If not: execute ``rollback transaction;``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `amount` is stored as an integer.  If you want decimal places, you first need to change it to something that supports decimals.  Perhaps:

```
alter table transaction alter amount decimal(19, 4);
```

Then this should work:

```
Update transaction
    set amount = amount / 100.0
    where id = 20;
```